# In Mail, Cmd-Opt-Ctrl-F does something unexpected

Tags: macos, keyboard, mail.app, shortcut

I would like to assign Cmd-Opt-Ctrl-F to flag an email item, but that combination in mail is already assigned somewhere, and I cannot find where that is.

1. It is not in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts.
2. It does not seem to be on any of the Mail menus.

The action that it causes seems to be "position to a specific mail item in one of the folders".

So I deleted that mail item. Then Cmd-Opt-Ctrl-F did not do anything, so I thought. So I went into System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts and set it up.

Now when I press that combination, instead of flagging the item as desired, it positions to a different mail item in the same folder. And always that exact item.

Any ideas where Cmd-Opt-Ctrl-F is being assigned, and why it has such a weird action?

Answer (score 1):

In Mavericks Mail:

The shortcut for Flag is <kbd>shift</kbd>- <kbd>cmd</kbd> - <kbd>L</kbd> to assign the Urgent Flag.

There is no Cmd-Opt-Ctrl-F in my Mail app.

However, if you try to add that shortcut in keyboard shortcut it will alert you if that short cut is used by someone else and show you by whom.

Comment: Cmd-Opt-Ctrl-F can be assigned. It just does not work. Instead it repositions to a specific email. It would be useful if there was a way of seeing what was assigned. For a long time I was able to use Cmd-Opt-Ctrl-L with a different app, but then suddenly, that stopped working and I cannot tell why. So it might be not specifically a Mail issue, but a more general system-wide issue of assignments. But the Shortcut assignment "should" say if there is a conflict, but it is not.

Comment: there should be a small yellow triangle if you try to assign a key that is already used!

Comment: As I said above, it lets me assign it and does not give a yellow triangle. But it does not work. I understand that it "should" present the small yellow triangle as you say. It should, but it does not. Whether Cmd-Opt-Ctrl-F is assigned or not assigned, sending that combo does the same thing, which is to move to a specific mail item. It is as though that mail item added the shortcut to the system, telling the system to "give me the focus". If I could post screen shots or screencasts, then I could show you.